# Query search. Return a list of results instead of just the first. By prefix substring

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get all objects which has the searchWord as a substring, in the column symbol.

if the searchWord is G, and there's five stock objects that exist:

```
GOOG
APPL
FLO.CO
GARY
OEGP
```

Then I'd like to retrieve `GOOG` and `GARY` but not `OEGP`. Just the prefix substring

Below is a scrap of code I've tried. But it'll just return one object.

```
    results = stock.objects.all().filter(symbol=searchWord)

    for x in results:
        print(x.symbol)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-startswith) with [`QuerySet.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#filter). Your ORM query should be as:

```
results = stock.objects.all().filter(symbol__startswith=searchWord)
```

This will check for the *case-sensitive* `searchWord` as prefix for the values in `symbol` column. In case you want to do *case-insensitive* prefix check, use [`istartswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe list comprehension works for you (corrected).

```
results = [r for r in results if r.startswith(searchWord)]
```

Comment: `searchWord in r` will check `searchWord` as substring in `r`. Better way will be to do `if r.starswith(searchWord in r):` to make a check for prefix. Also, list comprehension is not need here when you can decrease the load with `filter()` itself

Comment: You are correct. I didn't see that the OP only wanted words starting with `searchWord`. My expectation is that the OP wants a list in the end anyways.

Comment: Please excuse typo in previous comment. It is `r.starswith(searchWord)`. As a response to your comment, why to do `1+1+1+1+1+1` when you can get the same result by `1*6`? Hope you got it :)